Mapping two Dirichlet Distributions into a comparative Dirichlet
Assume I observe some draws from 2 choice options, and want to infer the probabilities of various outcomes, e.g. non-negative integers up to a limit L. I could simply use 2 Dirichlet distributions to count the outcomes I observe from the draws. My question is whether there is any way to map such Dirichlets into a "Comparative Dirichlet" that gives me the probability of obtaining x in one option and y in the other. Ideally, I would like to 1) order the two Dicihlets by increasing outcomes, and 2) obtain a comparative state-space. Importantly, I would like to be able to calculate both my inferred mean probability, and the confidence I have in that estimate.
Let us take a very simple example. Assume that I have 6 samples from option A, 1 resulting in 12 and 5 resulting in 0. Also assume that I draw 5 samples from option B, all of which result in draws of 3.
I am now interested in the probability that option A yields 12 while option B yields 3 (and in the probability of option A yielding 0 while option B yields 3). Ideally, I would obtain something like a "comparative Dirichlet" (or Beta) for this.
Is something like this possible, and what additional assumptions do I need? In particular, I would like to obtain not only the mean, but also a measure of the confidence, i.e. something akin to the total number of draws in the single-state Dirichlets, but now for the comparative Dirichlet.
Any help would be much appreciated!
